# How to resolve runtime exception The invocation of the constructor on type 'Esri.ArcGISRuntime.UI.Controls.MapView'

Tags: c#, arcgis-runtime, visual-c++-2017, arcgis-runtime-net

I was developing a GIS Windows Forms application using ArcGISRuntime SDK(version 100.4.0) in Visual Studio 2015. When I deploy the application exe in deployment machine(windows 10 machine with no visual studio environment) application worked properly. After that I shifted to Visual Studio 2017. The application was working properly in developers machine. But, when I deploy the exe in deployment machine(without VS2017 setup) it is throwing below exception:

> 'The invocation of the constructor on type 'Esri.ArcGISRuntime.UI.Controls.MapView' that matches the specified binding constraints threw an exception.'

After that I have gone through the below Link:

https://developers.arcgis.com/net/latest/wpf/guide/system-requirements.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_F2655B7F48F7464DB86CC7756706296D

It shows below requirements are compulsory for ArcGIS dependent application deployment:

1. Windows 10
2. Microsoft .NET Framework version 4.6.1 or later
3. Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2017

My deployment machine satisfies first two requirements. So I installed Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2017 on my deployment machine. But, still the problem is not resolved.

Please help me in solving this problem.

Comment: Please check the version of MS Visual C++ Redistributable.  VS comes with a bunch of them.

Comment: Also note that there's both an x64 and x86 version of the redistrib. If you have the "Prefer 32bit" flag set in your project settings, your app will run as 32bit so you'll need the 32bit version installed (safest is to just install both)

Answer (score 0):

After some R&D I found out that I was using ArcGISRuntime  dll's of 32 bit.  Visual C++ redistributable package is not installed on my deployment machine. So first I tried with installation of 64 bit version of that package but, it didn't work. Then I install 32 version which resolved my problem. Hope this helps.